# How to fix this issue?

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

When I do this command:

```
~ sudo aptitude purge nvidia-375          

The following packages will be REMOVED:     nvidia-375{p}  0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 4 not upgraded. Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 300 MB will be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y 
(Reading database ... 518122 files and directories currently installed.) Removing nvidia-375 (375.20-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1) ... 
Removing all DKMS Modules Error! There are no instances of module: nvidia-375
375.20 located in the DKMS tree. Done. 
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "/usr/bin/quirks-handler", line 26, in <module>
    import Quirks.quirkapplier ImportError: No module named 'Quirks' dpkg: error processing package nvidia-375 (--purge):  subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 1 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu4) ... 
Errors were encountered while processing:  nvidia-375 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) 
Failed to perform requested operation on package.  Trying to recover:
```

How to fix?

Comment: Using the `terminal` app, edit your question to include the output of `dkms status` and `dpkg -l *nvidia*`.